# How to set up search option for a charity website

Tags: html, css, search

I wonder if you could help me, I'm a graphic designer but trade with super basic HTML experience.

I'm volunteering for a small charity in Birmingham who is looking to create a community planning tool, I said I'll try and help design it, for free of course.

One of main options on the site is people can search to get resources. This is the interface:
[image]

Is there a really simple way to link this up?
For example, if someone clicked 'Balsall Heath Ward' and then 'Community' in the drop down menus then clicked search now it will take them to BHcommunity.html which will have resources. Same if somebody clicked 'Moseley Ward' and then clicked 'Sustainability' then search now, it would take them to MWsustainability.html. Does that make sense?

Basically I just need something that commands to point towards links, but I don't know where to start, can anybody give me some advice or help?

If anybody can help I can swop for free design support?

Thanks so much for the support!

Nath

Ps: Here is the code.

```
<h3 class="demo-panel-title">Fill out the relevant information:</h3>
<div class="col-xs-3"> <div class="form-group has-error"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What is your name?" class="form-control" /> </div> </div>
<div class="col-xs-3"> <div class="form-group has-success"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What is your email address?" class="form-control" /> <span class="input-icon fui-check-inverted"></span> </div> </div>
<div class="col-xs-3"> <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" value="" placeholder="What organisation are you associated with?" class="form-control" /> </div> </div>
<br/>
<div class="col-xs-3"> <h3 class="demo-panel-title">Which Ward do you want to explore?</h3> <select class="form-control select select-primary" data-toggle="select"> <option value="0">Moseley & Kings Heath Ward</option> <option value="1">Balsall Heath Ward</option> </select> </div>
<br/> <div class="col-xs-3"> <h3 class="demo-panel-title">What data do you need?</h3> <select class="form-control select select-primary" data-toggle="select"> <option value="0">Choose one</option> <option value="1">Local economy</option> <option value="2">Transport</option> <option value="3">Leisure</option> <option value="4" selected>Housing</option> <option value="5">Community</option> <option value="6">Planning</option> <option value="7">Sustainability</option> </select> </div> <br/>
```

I'd need to add a way to search

Comment: where do you get the expected results? do you have databases?

Comment: If you are going to do this properly you need to review some tutorials on javascript and event handling. Particularly "click" events. Looking at Html forms would be beneficial as well.

Comment: I'll write you up something to get this started as the midlands is close to my heart and you're doing a good thing. You will find though that StackOverflow is not really the best place to come looking for people to do things for you, this is a facility for learning and knowledge sharing.

Comment: Nique Joe - They will just go to HTML pages that have content on them, depending on what they search.

Comment: @yoda - Oh thank's, is there anything I can do for you in return?

Comment: @scrappedcola - More than happy to learn, just took it on with a deadline looming and I'm doing it for free, haha it's fairly stressful. Going forward and if I had more time I would defiantly teach myself via tutorials.

Comment: The mozilla developer network is a very solid place for tutorials and references. To add to Yoda's answer it will be a good place to read through and find more examples on what he's got setup for you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: If you're happy you can click the tick and accept my answer. My email address is typeof.developer@gmail.com feel free to get in touch. I'm interested in helping charitable organisations where i can so might be worth a chat.

Answer (score 2):

I have put together a reasonably simple example of how to do this, linked below. Firstly I have modified your HTML a little, changing the value attributes of your options to be more descriptive. I have added some IDs to elements for ease of location without the need for jQuery as you can see in the small extract here:

```
<div class="col-xs-3"> 
  <h3 class="demo-panel-title">What data do you need?</h3> 
  <select id="data-type-select" class="form-control select select-primary" data-toggle="select"> 
    <option value="0">Choose one</option> 
    <option value="economy">Local economy</option> 
    <option value="transort">Transport</option> 
    <option value="leisure">Leisure</option> 
    <option value="housing" selected>Housing</option> 
    <option value="community">Community</option> 
    <option value="planning">Planning</option> 
    <option value="sustainability">Sustainability</option> 
  </select> 
</div>
```

In the javascript I have kept it as simple as possible, I hope you can see how I have gathered the information and used it to pick which html file you want to go to.

```
(function() {
  function attachEvents () {
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('ward-information-submit-button');
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitButtonListener);
  }

  function submitButtonListener () {
    getFormData();
  }

  function getFormData () {
    var selectWardElement = document.getElementById('ward-select');
    var selectDataTypeElement = document.getElementById('data-type-select');

    pickDestination({
        selectedWard: selectWardElement.options[selectWardElement.selectedIndex].value,
        selectedDataType: selectDataTypeElement.options[selectDataTypeElement.selectedIndex].value
    });
  }

  function pickDestination (options) {
    if (options.selectedWard === 'moseley' && options.selectedDataType === 'economy') {
        console.log('MWsustainability.html');
        window.location = 'MWsustainability.html';
    }

    if (options.selectedWard === 'balsall' && options.selectedDataType === 'community') {
        console.log('BHcommunity.html');
        window.location = 'BHcommunity.html';
    }
  }

  attachEvents();
}());
```

I have a working version of this here which includes some additional comments to hopefully help you make sense of it. You will need to extend this code to make it work for all of your cases and I'm sure there are other requirements you have which you could apply these concepts to. Keep me updated and I'll help you learn where I can.

I appreciate the offer of something in return but it is unnecessary, just keep paying it forward as you are now. Good luck!

https://jsfiddle.net/rvb56sx6/

Answer (score 0):

You may consider making a JSON file or Javascript Object that holds string values for all the links you need. Then make a function that gets the values of the dropdown menus and chooses a link accordingly. Also, consider using Jquery to simplify this process. ( I use it in this example. **Meaning that it must be used if you want to use the below function**). You can include it by adding the below script tag in your html before you add the script tag for the file with the below function.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/JS/File/with/below/function"></script>
```

#### Javascript Object

```
var links = { 
  balsallHeathWard {
    community: '<Link to community>'
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

#### Javascript Function

```
$(function goToLink() {
  $(document).on('click', '#<submitButtonIdName>', function(){
    var ward = $('#<wardChooserSelectTagIdName>').val();
    var subchoice = $('#<subChoiceTagIDName>').val();
    if(ward == "Balsall Heath Ward") {
      if(subchoice == "Community") {
        window.location.href = links.balsallHeathWard.community;
      } else if ...
     ...
    } else if ...
    ...
  });
})();
```

The function would look something like the function above. I couldn't complete it because I don't have all the options and links that you have for what can be chosen from the charity website. But this is a general idea. It definitely needs work though, but I am willing to help if you need it (I have a soft spot for charities).

Comment: You should add that the Op needs to include jQuery and possibly how to do so.

Comment: Yoda - thank you so much, if you can pop me an email address I'll pass it on to the charity to say thank you?

Thank you everybody, lovely people :)